# WIN API To Check For Window Responsiveness

Tags: winapi

Is there a WINAPI to check if a certain window is "Not Responsive"? or get its responsiveness level?

Comment: [`SendMessageTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) either comes you back from responsive window, or timeout occurs.

Comment: The is also the unsupported `IsHungAppWindow ` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633526